# How to implement an iOS custom animation that redraws the view every frame?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, caanimation

I need a custom UIView that changes its appearance all the time, however, its change is not on a property keypath, thus cannot be expressed with `CABasicAnimation` or `CATransition`. I need to redraw the view/layer for every frame (think game main loop).

I can think of several ways to do this:

- Set a repeating NSTimer that calls the view's `setNeedsDisplay`. Many people think this will slow down the app.
- Use `CADisplayLink`:

  `let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(step))`
     `displaylink.add(to: .current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)`

  I am not sure I should call `setNeedDisplay` or `draw` method in the step function. And I don't know if this is different from method 1.
- Implement a subclass of `CAAnimation`, and implement its `CAAction` protocol and redraw the view there.

I wonder which one is the most efficient and doesn't slow down my app, and why it is more efficient than the other methods (like maybe do the actual drawing on another thread)?